# stickyfloat not working on absolute positioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

Here's the deal. I have a small div who is `position: absolute;`. I'm using [stickyfloat](https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat) plugin to make it scroll ONLY within the `<section class="software-content"></section>`, like the demo they show on the github page. However this absolutely positioned div, where the menu is, instead of scrolling with the browser, it instead scrolls ALL the way to the top. I have no idea why it is having this behaviour. Here's a fiddle demonstrating it:

http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/19amn27z/1/

Note: Summary the above fiddle for some reason, does not emulate the behaviour. The `div.store-menu` element should scroll within the `section.softwate-content` element and stop as the user scrolls down into the `div.prefooter` element.

Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Fiddle has not that library, and that why we cant test it in fiddle

Comment: My bad, it's 4am in the morning. Updating it!

Comment: u forget updating question with new fiddle (its like http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/19amn27z/2 )

Answer (score 0):

Try that way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    t = function(){$('.scroll-store-menu').stickyfloat({duration: 400, lockBottom: true});}
    setTimeout(t, 50);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/19amn27z/2/

Comment: This is what I have on the javascript section, take a look!

Comment: no, u have $('.scroll-store-menu').stickyfloat({duration: 400, lockBottom: true}); with another selector

Comment: my bad, sorry - i looking old fiddle, wait for seconds

Comment: doesn't even work with the selector. `div.scroll-store-menu` is the main container of the menu.

Comment: Nope. Same thing. I think I'm just going to give up with this idea. Going to design a new concept for that menu.

Comment: cant fix it, sorry ( mb try it a little bit later, dont give up